Error: Authentication error (10000) With Gitlab Pipeline and terraform-provider-cloudflare
We needed to move our domain which is using cloudflare for dns server, to another account in cloudflare. After the migration was done, we have created another API-token in the new account with the same permissions in the new account and then the problem ocure. When try to run the pipeline i get this error: (The Api token is changed with the new one in the gitlab server)
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.
╷
│ Error: Authentication error (10000)"

What have I done so far trying to debug with no success. (I use cloudflare_record with the terraform)

Check if the server have access to cloudflare and have permision to read and write in the zone with:

curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<zone_id>/dns_records" -H "X-Auth-Email:<auth_email>" -H "Authorization: Bearer <api_token>" -H "Content-Type:application/json" | jq . | tee importedcloudflare.json

I get the error in the plan state so this curl prove that the token have access to read the records in the zone.

Originaly the token is set like a variable which is defined in the gitlab CI/CD option. For the testing purposes I even set the token in plain text in the terraform recept and the error still persist.

In the gitlab runner config.toml file i have set



disable_cache = true

And then clear the cache from the gitlab pipeline menu. To eliminate any possible chance of caching I even build another container to execute the job. Still no success and the error remain. (One thing that i missed is to set another runner and try run the job with it.)

Build the very same gitlab server with the same config and same setup. Copy/Paste all the files, Create the same projects which are needed for this terraform recept to work and then magic the recept is working.

Where could be the problem, because I can't afford to move all the project to a new server only because of a one faulty pipeline. The terraform versions are the same in the both gitlab servers which are also with the same version as well the operating systems the kernels etc. The two servers and the configed project for terraform-cloudflare are the same. Sorry if I miss something and for my bad grammar it is not my native language.
